# Editable ReactJS MUI Datagrid component showing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, typeerror, mui-x-data-grid

I am using React Data Table component from MUI (material UI) but i need to customize it such that i can create a marksheet.

The error is as follows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') at GridRow.js:180:1 at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3733:1) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3777:1) at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:3834:1) at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:3848:1) at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:7992:1) at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8018:1) at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8029:1) at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8038:1) at react-dom.development.js:8198:1 at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22595:1) at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3581:1) at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8197:1) at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:5703:1) at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5697:1) at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5674:1) it shows the following error

I have tried the following updating all dependencies.
I have tried runnning it on sandbox and stackblitz with same dependecies but the error does show up there.

Following is the output
Here is the code: Please help
[text](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-euclid-k4m9hi?file=/package.json)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 60,},

    { field: 'subject', 
    headerName: 'Subject',
    width: 180, 
    editable: true, },

    { field: 'mark',
    headerName: 'Marks (Out of 100)',
    editable: true,},
];

const rows = [
    {
        id: 1,
        subject: "Subject 1",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        subject: "Subject 2",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        subject: "Subject 3",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        subject: "Subject 4",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        subject: "Subject 5",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        subject: "Subject 6",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        subject: "Subject 7",
        mark: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        subject: "Subject 8",
        mark: 0,
    }
];
export default function AddResult(props) {

    const handleCellEditCommit = React.useCallback((params) => {
    const { id, field, value } = params;
    const updatedRows = rows.map((row) => {
        if (row.id === id) {
            return { ...row, [field]: value };
        }
            return row;
        });
        console.log('Updated Rows:', updatedRows);
    }, []);
    

    return (
    <>
        <form>
            <label htmlFor='resultTitle'> Add Result Title</label>
            <input type='text' id='resultTitle' />

            <label htmlFor='remarks'> Add Remarks</label>
            <input type='text' id='remarks' />
        </form>

        <div style={{ height: 500, width: '100%' }}> 
        <DataGrid 
            rows={rows} columns={columns} 
            onCellEditCommit={handleCellEditCommit}
            hideFooter
            />
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>Total</h3>
            <h3>100</h3>
            <h3>Percentage</h3>
            <h3>Total</h3>
        </div>
    </>
    );
    }
```